# How to correctly use '[iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new()' to read a simple PDF document?

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext

So I was finally able to correctly load itext and avoid getting the errors I was getting [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77498257/itext7-getting-a-cannot-find-file-error-when-attempting-to-read-a-pdf-documen/77498328#77498328).

```
Add-Type -path 'C:/itext_2/itext.8.0.2/lib/netstandard2.0/itext.kernel.dll'
Add-Type -path 'C:\itext_2\itext.commons.8.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.commons.dll'
Add-Type -path 'C:/itext_2/itext.8.0.2/lib/netstandard2.0/itext.io.dll'

Add-Type -path 'C:/itext_2/common.logging.3.4.1/lib/netstandard1.3/Common.Logging.dll'
Add-Type -path 'C:/itext_2/common.logging.core.3.4.1/lib/netstandard1.0/Common.Logging.Core.dll'

$reader = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:/itext_2/hello-world.pdf")
```

I don't get any error at all this time. Running `$reader` returns `iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader`:

```
$reader | Get-Member

   TypeName: iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader

Name                       MemberType Definition
----                       ---------- ----------
Close                      Method     void Close()
ComputeUserPassword        Method     byte[] ComputeUserPassword()
Dispose                    Method     void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals                     Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetCryptoMode              Method     int GetCryptoMode()
....
```

Reading the official documentation, it looks like I need to pass this `$reader` object to [`[iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new()`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.2/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_document.html). When I try to do that

```
$PdfDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($reader)
```

I get an error:

```
MethodInvocationException:
Line |
   9 |  $PdfDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($reader)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'iText.Commons.Actions.EventManager' threw an exception."
```

I have uploaded a copy of the sample pdf file I am trying to read from [HERE](https://www.docdroid.net/vNdTCGx/hello-world-pdf).

As much as I have tried to roll my sleeves and figure this out on my own, I am facing a number of issues, itext is an upgrade of itextsharp, so most examples are in itextsharp.

The official documentation is also in csharp, I dont know any csharp so its hard to read it.

My code above is following this question, [Upgrading from iTextSharp to iText7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68626161/upgrading-from-itextsharp-to-itext7), one of the few example on the new itext (even then they are comparing old and new ways).

If anyone can share with me, how to read the PDF I linked to or any other in PowerShell, or help with solving the above error, I would really appreciate it.